# How to change Facebook GIF image link description

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, animated-gif

I am using graph API to post a GIF image to Facebook.
The image is getting posted, but I want to change the link description.

In the below picture, LH3.GOOGLEUSERCONTENT.COM is displayed as the picture description even after I gave description and caption.

Here is my function call

```
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', {
    link: url,
    description: "test",
    caption: "test",
    source: url,
    privacy: {
        value: "EVERYONE"
    }
}, function (response) {
    //some code
});
```

Can anyone help me??

[image: Facebook image]

Comment: Facebook is in the process of removing the ability to pass parameters such as title, description, caption and thumbnail at runtime, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_9_90_day_deprecations All of this data will be taken from the Open Graph meta tags of the URL you share.

Comment: But I am sharing the link of an image. Where should I put the metatags then?

Comment: You can’t. Share a proper HTML document that uses the image as thumbnail.

Comment: Then it will display like a page, right? The image on left side and title and description on the right side.

Comment: That depends on the image dimensions. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images

Comment: oh ok. Thanks for the help. I will use meta tags then.